# Testing transactionality of IBM Integration Bus

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

In order to improve my flows, I would like to test a few scenarios in which the flow/App or Integration Node is stopped while the message is still being processed (to test how transactional my flows actually are, depending on different settings). As IIB9 is fast with processing simple requests, I don't have the time to shut down the flow quickly enough.
I tried to use the debugger, but that doesn't seem to work; I cannot stop the flow or App while debugging, and shutting down the Integration Node doesn't seem to work well either.

Is there an (in-build) way to make the broker work really slowly so I have the time to shut it down? Or should I just think of a really complicated compute node to keep it occupied for a few seconds?

Any suggestions (also for the latter if that is the best option) are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really complicated compute node will take a lot of CPU. I would prefer making flow wait for something.

Eg. A flow with HTTP request node or SOAP request node making call to external service. Make this external service take time like say 120 seconds.

Comment: That is a good idea, didn't think of that. And making it throw an exception, will that have the same effect?

Comment: I also found the function SLEEP that you can use. Might also be a possibility.

Comment: SLEEP function is also a good idea. It will give you enough time to go and stop execution group. One thing to keep in mind is SLEEP gets interrupted as soon as you issue mqsistopmsgflow command. You may add some code after SLEEP and verify that it gets executed.